# Xamarin: GetFromLocationAsync returning null

Tags: xamarin, gps, geocoding, reverse

I called `GetFromLocationAsync` using the method below, however, it’s returning a `null`.

```
var addresses = await geo.GetFromLocationAsync(42.37419, -71.120639, 10);
```

**I have assigned the app the appropriate permissions**.

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
```

Please let me know what I’m doing wrong.

Regards,
Jason.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or emulator? Also the device/emulator needs access to the internet to be able to reverse geocode using google API.

Comment: I have tried both and I have internet access.